# Partition algorithm average-case complexity analysis

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, quicksort, average-case

I was given the following algorithm:

```
PARTITION(A,p,r)
x <- A[p]
i <- p
j <- r
repeat
    while A[i]<x
        do i<-i+1
    while A[j]>x
        do j<-j-1
    if i <= j
        then exchange A[i] <-> A[j]
until i>j
return i,j

quicksort(A, p, r):
    if p<r
    then i,j <- PARTITION(A,p,r)
    QUICKSORT(A, p, j)
    QUICKSORT(A, i, r)
```

And I was asked to find the quicksort run time at best, worst and average cases.
I did okay for the best and worst, however I'm having difficulties with the average case. I'm pretty sure it's still $O(nlgn)$, but I can't prove it formally, mainly showing how many time the partition method is called at most.

Could anyone help me with that?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: There have to be dozens of good sources out there that cover this. Do you have a specific question? "but I can't prove it formally, mainly showing how many time the partition method is called at most" -- you don't need "at most", you need "in expectation". Hint: what's the expected rank of the pivot?

Comment: I'm learning from Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms", and trying the same approach that is being used to calculate the average-case of the standard quicksort algorithm, which starts by declaring the maximum calls for partiotion.